# Matlab to Python conversion of rand()

Tags: python, matlab, random, code-conversion

In Matlab I have the following:

```
duration = 20
n=5
times = rand(1,n)*duration;
```

The variable "times" gives a 1-by-n matrix, which is populated with random numbers between 0 and 1, then multiplied by 20. This will result in a set of 5 numbers between 0 and 20.

Now I want to achieve the same in Python, what would be the equivalent? 
I tried the following:

```
times = random.uniform(1,durations,n)  %% or times = random.uniform(1,20,5)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: uniform() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

which does not make sense to me, because I only seem to have given it 3 arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) only accepts the upper and lower bounds of your random numbers. You will want to call `random.uniform` `n` times to create a list of random values.

```
values = [random.uniform(0, 20) for _ in range(5)]
```

Alternately, you could use [`numpy.random.rand`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand) to do this similarly to MATLAB and the function will return a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
values = np.random.rand(1, 5) * 20
```

If you are converting much code from MATLAB to Python, `numpy` is  recommended over using standard datatypes due to it's computational speed and similar behavior to MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and solutions! Indeed, this works, I tried the numpy version!